# Integral property for 2-forms

Tags: differential-forms

Let us assume that the 2-forms $dg\wedge dh$, $df \wedge dh$ and $df\wedge dg$ are exact. Is there any proof that the following identity holds

$\int f\,dg \wedge dh=\int h\, df\wedge dg=\int g\, dh\wedge df$

for periodic boundary conditions? $f,g,h$ are 0-forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It holds more generally than that. You have e.g.:
$$ d(f  g\, dh) = f \, dg \wedge dh + g \, df \wedge dh $$
So if your boundary conditions assure that the integral of  $f g \, dh$ along the boundary vanishes then you arrive at
$$ \int \int f \, dg \wedge dh -  g \, dh \wedge df =0$$

Comment: Oh thank you! Is there anything analogous for 3-forms? i.e. $\int f\, dg\wedge dh\wedge dk=-\int g\, df\wedge dh\wedge dk$  ??

Comment: yes, you may do the same calculation for $d(f  g \, dh\wedge dk)$ but you need a special geometry in order for the boundary integral to vanish. This is also the case in the example you stated, e.g. it works on a torus.